# How to implement a simple neural network using keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

Using the following libraries:

```
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from keras import optimizers
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten
```

I need to create a simple network as shown:

[image]

The NN should take a tensor the same shape as our digits as input. The first hidden layer should output 300 dimensional vector and use sigmoid as the activation function. The second hidden layer should also output 300 dimensional vector and use relu as the activation function. The third hidden layer (i.e., the output layer) should output the size of prediction and use a softmax activation at the end for multi-class classification

For now, I have:

```
model = None

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, input_shape=(300,)))
model.add(Activation(___))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(6))
model.add(Activation(___))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(7))
model.add(Activation(___))
```

I am not sure what goes into Dense. I just referenced it from here https://keras.io/api/models/sequential/

I understand that the first activation function should be sigmoid, where sigmoid is `1/(1 + np.exp(-x))`

I also know that relu is `max(0.0, x)` and softmax is

```
def softmax(vector):
    e = exp(vector)
    return e / e.sum()
```

However I am unsure of how to put all of these together to create a neural network and get output:

[image]

If anyone is willing to help, I would be deeply appreciative as it is my first time attempting to initialise a neural network. Thank you!

Comment: Keras has a bunch of examples in the website and github, have you looked at those? Or at the documentation? Also note that Keras has implementations of these activations already.

Comment: see keras documentation for [activations](https://keras.io/api/layers/activations/) - and you will see `tf.keras.activations.sigmoid(x)`, `tf.keras.activations.softmax(x, axis=-1)`, `tf.keras.activations.relu(x, alpha=0.0, max_value=None, threshold=0.0)`

Comment: in documentation for `activations` you can also see `Dense(..., activation='softmax')` `Dense(..., activation='relu')`, etc.

Comment: what is the size of `digits` ? In first layer you should use `input_shape=(digit_size,)`

Answer (score 3):

In documentation for [keras.layers.activations](https://keras.io/api/layers/activations/) you can see

```
tf.keras.activations.sigmoid(x)
tf.keras.activations.softmax(x, axis=-1) 
tf.keras.activations.relu(x, alpha=0.0, max_value=None, threshold=0.0)
```

So code could be:

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential(name='sequential_2')

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(300, name='dense_5', input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation(tf.keras.activations.sigmoid, name='activation_5'))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(300, name='dense_6'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation(tf.keras.activations.relu, name='activation_6'))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, name='dense_7'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation(tf.keras.activations.softmax, name='activation_7'))

model.summary()
```

Result:

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 dense_5 (Dense)             (None, 300)               235500    
                                                                 
 activation_5 (Activation)   (None, 300)               0         
                                                                 
 dense_6 (Dense)             (None, 300)               90300     
                                                                 
 activation_6 (Activation)   (None, 300)               0         
                                                                 
 dense_7 (Dense)             (None, 10)                3010      
                                                                 
 activation_7 (Activation)   (None, 10)                0         
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 328,810
Trainable params: 328,810
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

---

Using different `imports` you can reduce code and still get the same `summary`:

```
#import tensorflow as tf  # no need it at this moment
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.activations import sigmoid, relu, softmax

model = Sequential(name='sequential_2')

model.add(Dense(300, name='dense_5', input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Activation(sigmoid, name='activation_5'))

model.add(Dense(300, name='dense_6'))
model.add(Activation(relu, name='activation_6'))

model.add(Dense(10, name='dense_7'))
model.add(Activation(softmax, name='activation_7'))

model.summary()
```

But you can also reduce code to get the same model:

```
#import tensorflow as tf  # no need it at this moment
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential(name='sequential_2')

model.add(Dense(300, name='dense_5', activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Dense(300, name='dense_6', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10,  name='dense_7', activation='softmax'))

model.summary()
```

but `summary` will be also reduced:

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 dense_5 (Dense)             (None, 300)               235500    
                                                                 
 dense_6 (Dense)             (None, 300)               90300     
                                                                 
 dense_7 (Dense)             (None, 10)                3010      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 328,810
Trainable params: 328,810
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

You can also skip `name=` to reduce code.

```
#import tensorflow as tf  # no need it at this moment
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(300, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Dense(300, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10,  activation='softmax'))

model.summary()
```

---

**BTW:**

If you want to work with `MNIST` which have images with shape `(28,28)` then you could add layer `Flatten` to automatically convert shape `(28,28)` to shape `(784)`

```
#import tensorflow as tf  # no need it at this moment
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten

model = Sequential()

#model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1,28,28)))
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)))
model.add(Dense(300, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(300, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10,  activation='softmax'))

model.summary()
```

Result:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 784)               0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 300)               235500    
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 300)               90300     
                                                                 
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 10)                3010      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 328,810
Trainable params: 328,810
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

And if you use `summary()` after `fit()` then you can even skip `input_shape=(28,28)` in `Flatten()` because `fit()` will set it.

---

**EDIT:**

Full working code.

Tested on `tensorflow 2.8.0`, `Python 3.10`, `Linux Mint 21.0` (based on `Ubuntu 22.04`)

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
#from keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy
from keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np

print('\n--- version ---\n')

print('tensorflow:', tf.__version__)
#print('tensorflow:', tf.version.VERSION)
#print('tensorflow:', keras.__version__)

print('\n--- data ---\n')

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
print('train.shape  :', x_train.shape)
print('test.shape   :', x_test.shape)

print('image.shape  :', x_train[0].shape)
print('image.flatten:', x_train[0].flatten().shape)

y_train = to_categorical(y_train)  # `Y` will have shape `(10)` and last layer will also need `Dense(10)`
y_test  = to_categorical(y_test)   # `Y` will have shape `(10)` and last layer will also need `Dense(10)`

print('\n--- model ---\n')

model = Sequential()

#model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1,28,28)))  # if `summary()` used before `fit()` then you have to set `input_shape`
model.add(Flatten())                        # if `summary()` used after  `fit()` then you can skip `input_shape` (because `fit` will set it)
model.add(Dense(300, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(300, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10,  activation='softmax'))

#model.compile(loss=categorical_crossentropy, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])  # function `categorical_crossentropy`
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])  # string `'categorical_crossentropy'`
print('\n--- fit/train ---\n')

batch_size = 20
epochs = 5

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=True, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

print('\n--- evaluate/test ---\n')

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=True)
print(score)

print('\n--- predict ---\n')

# for N-elements it needs shape `(N, 28, 28)`
# for single element it needs shape `(1, 28, 28)`, not `(28, 28)`
#items = x_test[0]                          # WRONG
#items = x_test[0][np.newaxis, ...]         # OK
#items = x_test[0][None, ...]               # OK
#items = x_test[0:1]                        # OK
#items = np.array( [x_test[0]] )            # OK
#items = np.expand_dims(x_test[0], axis=0)  # OK
#items = x_test[0].reshape(-1,28,28)        # OK
items = x_test[0].reshape(1,28,28)          # OK
print('items.shape:', items.shape)

results = model.predict(items)   # it needs `numpy.array` even for single element (shape: `(1, 28, 28)`)

for item in results:
    print('predict:', item)
    print('max    :', np.max(item))
    print('argmax :', np.argmax(item))    
    
#print('result:', results[0])
#print('max:', np.max(results[0]), np.argmax(results[0]))

print('\n--- summary ---\n')

model.summary() 

#print('\n--- show image ---\n')

#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#plt.imshow(x_test[0])
#plt.show()
```

Result:

```
--- version ---

tensorflow: 2.8.0

--- data ---

train.shape  : (60000, 28, 28)
test.shape   : (10000, 28, 28)
image.shape  : (28, 28)
image.flatten: (784,)

--- model ---

--- fit/train ---

Epoch 1/5
3000/3000 [==============================] - 26s 8ms/step - loss: 0.4459 - accuracy: 0.8600 - val_loss: 0.3425 - val_accuracy: 0.8907
Epoch 2/5
3000/3000 [==============================] - 31s 10ms/step - loss: 0.3133 - accuracy: 0.9011 - val_loss: 0.2753 - val_accuracy: 0.9128
Epoch 3/5
3000/3000 [==============================] - 22s 7ms/step - loss: 0.2702 - accuracy: 0.9153 - val_loss: 0.2291 - val_accuracy: 0.9271
Epoch 4/5
3000/3000 [==============================] - 22s 7ms/step - loss: 0.2482 - accuracy: 0.9218 - val_loss: 0.2142 - val_accuracy: 0.9346
Epoch 5/5
3000/3000 [==============================] - 21s 7ms/step - loss: 0.2246 - accuracy: 0.9292 - val_loss: 0.2061 - val_accuracy: 0.9362

--- evaluate/test ---

313/313 [==============================] - 2s 6ms/step - loss: 0.2061 - accuracy: 0.9362
[0.20612983405590057, 0.9362000226974487]

--- predict ---

items.shape: (1, 28, 28)
predict: [2.2065036e-08 3.6986236e-09 2.2580415e-04 2.4656517e-06 6.2174437e-12
 6.3476205e-07 1.2726037e-15 9.9974352e-01 1.7498225e-07 2.7370381e-05]
max    : 0.9997435
maxarg : 7

--- summary ---

Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 784)               0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 300)               235500    
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 300)               90300     
                                                                 
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 10)                3010      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 328,810
Trainable params: 328,810
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for the extremely detailed answer!

Comment: I added full working code - with `fit()`, `evaluate()`, and `predict()` (for single item)